# Binding knockoutjs / mapping in ASP.NET with EF objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am trying to bind a select and table to the result of an AJAX call in ASP.NET with the objects coming from EntityFramework backend.
Here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function QuizListViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.quizList = ko.observableArray([]);
    }

    var qlvm = new QuizListViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(qlvm);

    function FetchQuizzes() {

        $.getJSON(
            "/DesktopModules/personify/QuizAdminDos/API/QuizAdmin/QuizList",
            function (result) {
                var mapping = {
                    'observe': ["IdQuiz", "Name"]
                }
                parsedJsonQuizzes = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
                console.log(parsedJsonQuizzes);
                ko.mapping.fromJS(parsedJsonQuizzes, mapping, qlvm.quizList);
            });    
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        FetchQuizzes();
    });

</script>
```

Here is the View:

```
<select data-bind="options: quizList,
                   optionsText: function(quiz) { return quiz.Name() + '(Id: ' + quiz.IdQuiz() + ')'},
                   optionsCaption: 'Select a quiz...'"></select>
```

I have verified through debugging that I am getting objects back from my JSON call.  I have also verified that the 'quizList' observable has values after the ko.mapping.fromJS call.  However, nothing is showing in my select.  I don't even get the "optionsCaption" value.

Am I allowed to bind directly to EF objects (generated from the DB)?  Here is what is coming back from the console.log output of the parsedJsonQuizzes:

[image]
And for full disclosure, this is how I am returning the objects from my AJAX call:

```
    using (var db = new LinuxDatabase())
    {
        List<Quiz> qzs = db.Quizs.ToList();
        db.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(qzs);
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, json);
    }
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to move your call to `applyBindings` into your `$(documnent).ready` function so that you can ensure the DOM has been loaded before you're trying to bind.

Comment: Based on all the examples I have seen, you don't need to do this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/knockout
Although, I did try your solution, unfortunately it didn't work.